# Aerosmith Song "The Movie" has a woman speaking, what is she saying?

Tags: lyrics

It sounds like there is a woman speaking on the track "The Movie" from Permanent Vacation album.  Does anyone know what she is saying, or can it be translated into english?

Comment: Great question.  I've always wondered.  I am pretty sure it's some form of Russian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Aerosmith/comments/niknyr/the_movie/)
which mentions a  [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_Vacation_(Aerosmith_album)) for Aerosmith's "Permanent Vacation " album.

wiki page text :

> Drew Arnott – mellotron on "Angel" and "The Movie"

> Christine Arnott – backing vocals on "The Movie"

Drew Arnold , member of [band Strange Advance] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Advance).

reddit article also says

> Stands to reason these two would be related. Drew Arnott is in a band
> from Vancouver. I found [this
> obituary](https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/vancouversun/obituary.aspx?n=christine-arnott&pid=159884085)
> for a woman named Christine Arnott from the Vancouver Sun which
> mentions a son Drew, and says
>
> Chris joined the Vancouver Gaelic Society and sang in the Gaelic
> Choir, which allowed her to enjoy two of her favourite pastimes -
> singing and laughing. Her Gaelic skills even led her to appear on an
> Aerosmith album!

The obituary article also mentions :

> Chris was born October 14, in Glasgow, to John and Morag MacPherson.
> Mum loved to dance and spent many happy hours twirling around the
> dancehalls of Glasgow, especially the Highlanders Institute. She loved
> being on the Isle of Harris with her cousin Rachel and her aunt and
> uncle Nora and Donald John, where the Gaelic culture she enjoyed so
> much, thrived.

so the words would be [Scots Gaelic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Gaelic)

This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU98GzNopRU) has a description which lists the words :

> All the world’s a stage, And all the men and women merely players" ~
> Shakespeare Scots Gaidhlig, spoken by Christine Arnott,  Words and
> translation are:
>
> "Theid sinn dhachaidh am bliadhna seo 's bith ceilidh
> mhor againn,  We'll go home this year and we'll have a big ceilidh,
>
> 's theid sinn chun na Hearadh agus ni sin ceilidh air Nora agus
> Raonailt and we'll go to Harris and visit Nora and Rachel
>
> 's tha mi an dochas gu faigh sinn buntata agus sgadan. I hope we get
> potato and herring
>
> 'S theid sin gu Scalpaidh 's theid sinn a choimhead air Mairi agus And
> we'll go to Scalpay and visit Mairi and"......faded out under music

source credited by the YT poster is a broken yahoo link.....although the same is also quoted in a commment in the Amazon store for the same album.